# How to set onitemclick listener on custom ListView including image and text?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

1 .Model.java

```
public class Model{

private int icon;
private String title;


private boolean isGroupHeader = false;

public Model(String title) {

    setGroupHeader(true);
}
public Model(int icon, String title) {
    super();
    this.setIcon(icon);
    this.setTitle(title);

}
public boolean isGroupHeader() {
    return isGroupHeader;
}
public void setGroupHeader(boolean isGroupHeader) {
    this.isGroupHeader = isGroupHeader;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public int getIcon() {
    return icon;
}
public void setIcon(int icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

 //gettters & setters...
 }
```

This is my code of MyAdapter.java

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;

  public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Model> modelsArrayList;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> modelsArrayList) {

        super(context, R.layout.item1, modelsArrayList);

        this.context = context;
        this.modelsArrayList = modelsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // 1. Create inflater 
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // 2. Get rowView from inflater

        View rowView = null;
        if(!modelsArrayList.get(position).isGroupHeader()){
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, parent, false);

            // 3. Get icon,title & counter views from the rowView
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon); 
            TextView titleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);


            // 4. Set the text for textView 
            imgView.setImageResource(modelsArrayList.get(position).getIcon());
            titleView.setText(modelsArrayList.get(position).getTitle());

        }
        else{
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_header_item, parent, false);
                TextView titleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.header);
                titleView.setText(modelsArrayList.get(position).getTitle());

        }

        // 5. retrn rowView
        return rowView;
    }}
```

Here is my code of MainActivity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    // if extending Activity
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // 1. pass context and data to the custom adapter
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, generateData());

    // if extending Activity 2. Get ListView from activity_main.xml
    //ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    // 3. setListAdapter
    //listView.setAdapter(adapter); if extending Activity
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private ArrayList<Model> generateData(){
    ArrayList<Model> models = new ArrayList<Model>();
    models.add(new Model("Group Title 1"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Menu Item"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.app_icon,"Menu Item"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Menu Item 3"));
    models.add(new Model("Group Title 2"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Menu Item 1"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.app_icon,"Menu Item 2"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Menu Item 3"));
    models.add(new Model("Group Title 3"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Menu Item 1"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.app_icon,"Menu Item 2"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Menu Item 3"));

    return models;
}}
```

i have created a custom list view on my project.
how to setonclick listener to whole raw with image and text.

I have a problem creating separate onClickListeners for separate parts of the item. My item has a picture and a text. What I want is to start different activities depending on which of those has been clicked.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You must do the following:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // 1. Create inflater 
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // 2. Get rowView from inflater

    // I edited here
    final Model _model = modelsArrayList.get(position);

    View rowView = null;
    if(!_model.isGroupHeader()){
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, parent, false);

        // 3. Get icon,title & counter views from the rowView
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon); 
        TextView titleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);


        // 4. Set the text for textView 
        imgView.setImageResource(modelsArrayList.get(position).getIcon());
        titleView.setText(modelsArrayList.get(position).getTitle());

        // Set the listeners
        imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(_model is what you want){

                    //call your activity

                }

            }

        });

        titleView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(_model is what you want){

                    //call your activity

                }

            }

        });

    }
    else{
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_header_item, parent, false);
            TextView titleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.header);
            titleView.setText(modelsArrayList.get(position).getTitle());

    }

    // 5. retrn rowView
    return rowView;
}
```

Don't forget to add `android:clickable="true"` at your `ImageView` in the xml

Comment: Where is row position ?

Comment: There is no row position. That code is for all rows. What you have to do is get your object by `modelsArrayList.get(position)` so that you will work with each object

Comment: instantiating a new onClickListener every time `getView` is called is pretty bad design. now if someone were to scroll the list how many Listener objects would be generated and keep lying till GC collects them. Now you may not notice the jank/lag when your items' count is small but for a big number in >500 say it's a really bad design

Comment: I'll try giving an example - For every `getView` you create 2 `clickListeners` assume your screen space is available for 8 views at a given time and you have 16 items in the list then at first you create 16 objects of `listeners` now fast scroll to the next 8 and you multiply you `listener` objects by 2 and this can go on and on till GC intervenes.

Comment: @trpride you are almost right in this point, but everyone knows that we have to use `Holder` design to avoid it. Take a look this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html. So using `Holder` the listeners aren't called all the time

Comment: can any one give me a perfectly running example?

Comment: @trpride when i use  'if(_model is 1)'    its gives an error  **Type mismatch: cannot convert from Model to boolean**

Comment: It's because the `_model` is an object and not a boolean. What do you exactly wanna do? I mean, how do you know what `activity` you must call?

Comment: @ParthBhatti I think u want to check for position not sure though can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @Lennon I get your point, but, even then the minimum number of views that are active would be equal to your screen space and thus you'll end up creating atleast as many `listeners` as there are views on your screen. In my above example it'd be 8 for `listeners` for the whole list right? But if you make you `adapter` implement the `listener` then there is no instantiation per `recyclable view`.

Comment: @trpride what do i pick on "what you want"?  want a simple example

Comment: @trpride Even you do like you said would do the same thing, because you have to set for each component the adapter's listener like `textview.setOnClickListener(this)`. You have to agree with me that it would be the same, would't it?

Comment: @Lennon I don't think so because `this` refers to my adapters implementation only where as `new OnClickListener` would mean instantiating a new object. Don't you think so?

Comment: @ParthBhatti that is some criteria through which you discern which activity you want to show. I hope its not the same for every rows image and text view in which case you can forgo the check

Comment: @trpride Yes, but with `holders` there is no `new OnclickListener` all the time, so it is the same like you said. Moreover, @ParthBhatti wants two components with click listener. If he creates an unique `Onclick` method and set it for that two components, it would be a bad design, because he would have to check it out which component it is every click. Using `holders` is the best way to avoid that kind of thing. The own google's developers say that in their lectures.

Comment: @Lennon Alright let me rephrase myself using this question suppose I want this logic in my `listener` that for every even(%2 == 0) `item position` I want to execute a block of code. Now when do you set the `listener` on the `holder`. When the `convertView == null` or when you use the `tag`? This should make you reflect on this long discussion. Holders are faster cause they save re-instantiation which is exactly my point with the listeners.

Comment: @trpride Okay, I won't argue with you anymore unless you show me a better and proved example code of your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Make your adapter implement `View.OnClickListener` and set it to your `TextView` and `ImageView` then in the `onClick` of your implementation check the instance of view and perform different actions.

If you want something more complex to occur like different views in different rows behaving disjointly set `position` as `tag` to your views and read it in `onClick`

When I say set position as tag I mean `imgView.setTag(position)` & `titleView.setTag(position)` that way you can know the position in your `onClick` and be my guest on trying this out with a large sample set. This is a jank/lag free implementation. Generally as a rule of thumb you must avoid instantiating objects in `Adapter's` `getView()` because GC can make the main thread unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

Implement clickListener for ImageView and textView in getView() method of adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Thats done .

Just Create XML file of ListView (here is main.xml)

and set ListView (here is lv1)

REMEMBER :if you are `extends Activity` do not forgot to `setContentView` 
        And if you want to `extends ListActivity` do not use `setcontentView`

```
public class starting extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    // if extending Activity
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // 1. pass context and data to the custom adapter
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, generateData());

    // if extending Activity 2. Get ListView from activity_main.xml
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1);

    // 3. setListAdapter
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);// if extending Activity
    //setListAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch ( arg2 )
            {
            case 0 : Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fst opt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
            case 1 : Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sec opt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
            case 2 : Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "thrd opt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
            }
        }
    });
}

private ArrayList<Model> generateData(){
    ArrayList<Model> models = new ArrayList<Model>();
    models.add(new Model("Group Title 1"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Menu Item"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.app_icon,"Menu Item"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Menu Item 3"));
    models.add(new Model("Group Title 2"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Menu Item 1"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.app_icon,"Menu Item 2"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Menu Item 3"));
    models.add(new Model("Group Title 3"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Menu Item 1"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.app_icon,"Menu Item 2"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Menu Item 3"));

    return models;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can set onclick listener for the row view..

```
rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

Comment: where is position of row?

Comment: @ParthBhatti postion ??... if you want to set onclick listener for both text & image view .. then you can place the above code in getview..setting onclick listener for this  rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, parent, false);  won't require any position...